# Putevent on eventbus with Lambda with eventbridge sdk Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

All I wanted is to put some events on the event bus with Lambda using event bridge sdk which then can be picked up for the later activity.

This function tested fine when invoked on the local machine, somehow on AWS the event is lost and not picked up by event bus.

Sharing the basic code:

```
function _eventData(event: any): EventBusEvent {
  var eventData: BusEvent = {
    Source: 'events.mysource.update',
    DetailType: 'UpdateHasMade',
    Detail: JSON.stringify(event),
    EventBusName: 'arn:aws:events:ca-central-1:1111111111:event-bus/my-eventbus'
  };
  return {
    Entries: [eventData],
  };
}

// Create an Amazon EventBridge service client object.
export const ebClient = new EventBridgeClient({ region: 'ca-central-1' });

export async function dispatchEvent(event: any) {
  const eventData = _eventData(event);

  await ebClient
    .send(new PutEventsCommand(eventData))
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log('Success, event sent');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error');
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Have also checked for the Role policy for the above lambda, it has all permissions for
EventBridge and EventBridgeSchemas`

There is no error observed as such in logs, wondering what might be the issue here.

**Solution**:
Managed to resolve this issue with keeping eventbridge client call in handler itself rather than calling it from separate function.

Comment: What data are you getting logged after PutEvents? Are you getting back successful Entries or a FailedEntryCount? If it were a permissions error I would expect an error message saying something like "not authorized". 

If you are using a custom EventBus, you may want to check its permissions also, maybe it is missing something (especially if the bus and Lambda are on different accounts or regions):https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-bus-perms.html

Comment: I didn't getting any log for either success/failure. Eventbus and lambda all are on same account and region, that's what making it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is something wrong with your function implementation. Following official [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-eventbridge/classes/puteventscommand.html) I got this working for myself. Maybe it helps.

```
export async function sendSlackMessageToCustomEventBus(
  slackMessage: Record<string, BlockType>
): Promise<void> {
  const params = {
    Entries: [
      {
    Source: 'events.mysource.update',
    DetailType: 'UpdateHasMade',
    Detail: JSON.stringify(event),
    EventBusName: 'arn:aws:events:ca-central-1:1111111111:event-bus/my-eventbus'
  },
    ],
  };

  const eventBridgeClient = new EventBridgeClient({ region: region });
  const eventBridgeCommand = new PutEventsCommand(params);
  const result = await eventBridgeClient.send(eventBridgeCommand); // you do not have to store result in variable, its for testing 
}
```